# sched_yield flagged as top hotspot

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, intel-vtune

In analyzing a program with Vtune, I see that the `libc` function [`sched_yield`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=s-sched-yield-subroutine) is flagged as a significant hotspot.

Now I see that this function is roughly responsible for context switching; I say roughly because it's the first time I encounter this function, so my understanding is that it runs inside the OS scheduler to provide support for changing the active thread(s).

What does having `sched_yield` as a major hotspot, mean for my program? Does it mean that I create more threads than I should and the OS is trying to juggle continuous context switching?

What would be a remedy for this situation? Maybe resort to more centralized thread pools to avoid over-spawning threads?

What should I analyze next? Are there "typical" next steps in this situation? Vtune already suggests running an analysis for "threading".

Comment: The behavior of `sched_yield` largely depends on the OS. What OS are you running?

Comment: The expected behavior of sched_yield is to let something else run. From the point of view of a profiler the time between calling the function and returning from it would be counted as spent inside it. So maybe it's supposed to look like a hotspot?

Comment: Empirical rule of thumb: code using `sched_yield` is usually wrong, very wrong or deep magic™. Take a very long pole and don't touch it.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Debian 9

Comment: @dratenik `sched_yield` is not used directly, the codebase never calls it . Internal implementation of `std::thread` ends up "abusing" it, so I'm trying to figure out what it actually means

Comment: Is there a call graph that would indicate what feature of std::thread is behind it? Libc seems to only call yield on thread death.

Comment: @dratenik That's a very good observation, it would be my assumption as well. Instead of working with "long lived" thead pools, there are many threads created to run a single task and then die. So instead of "re-using" resources, new ones are created and discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does having `sched_yield` as a major hotspot, mean for my program?

On Linux, [`sched_yield`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_yield) does not necessarily switch to another thread to execute. The kernel does not deschedule the calling thread if there aren't threads that are ready to run *on the same CPU*. The last part is important, since the kernel will not reschedule a ready to run thread between CPUs upon this call. This is a design tradeoff, as `sched_yield` is supposed to be a low cost hint to the kernel.

Since `sched_yield` may just return immediately without doing anything, your code may act as having a busy loop around this call, which will look like a hot spot in your profile. Your code just loops around `sched_yield` a lot, without doing much else. Such spinning burns a lot of CPU cycles which could be spent for other threads and applications running on the system.

> What would be a remedy for this situation?

This depends a lot of your use case. Using `sched_yield` may be acceptable when you are willing to waste some CPU cycles in exchange for better latency. You have to be conscious about this decision, and even then I would recommend benchmarking a different solution, with proper thread blocking. Linux thread scheduler is quite efficient, so blocking and waking threads is not as expensive as on some other systems.

Often `sched_yield` is used in custom spin lock algorithms. I would recommend replacing these with pthread components, in particular `pthread_cond_t`, which allow to properly block and wake up threads. If you're using C++, there are equivalents in the standard library (e.g. [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)). In other cases it may be worth exploring other blocking APIs, such as [`select`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) and [epoll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html). The exact solution depends on your use case.